# Como hacer un multipart form data con express mediante postman

Tags: express, data, multipart

Quiero hacer un multipart form data con express desde postman

Explico el cotexto, necesito actulizar un archivo .csv y cuando se actualice mediante el postman quiero que ese archivo haga la conversion a un JSON y lo imprima como json

Ya tengo la parte de convertir el archivo a json pero me falta es actulizarlo mediante postman

Quedo atento

Comment: as intentado darle en body->form-data->text a file? y elegir la imagen que deseas?